# SQL query on a many to one with a status field

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine

I've got a table `post` with a many to one association with `news_feed`, structured as follows:

```sql
create table post
(
    id              int auto_increment   primary key,
    news_feed_id    int                  null,
    title           varchar(255)         not null,
    content         longtext             not null,
    status          int                  not null,
    created         datetime             not null,
    constraint FK_5A8A6C8D641A0E51
        foreign key (news_feed_id) references news_feed (id),
)

create table news_feed
(
    id              int auto_increment    primary key,
    enabled         tinyint(1) default 1  not null
)
```

`post` has a column called `status` which is an enum with three statuses. (These are enum values from 0-2, but I'll reference them by their names to make it clearer)

```
enum Status {
    VISIBLE_NONE,
    VISIBLE_ADMIN,
    VISIBLE_ALL
}
```

These statuses are determined by the user's relationship between a newsfeed. A user may be an admin for newsfeed 1, but not for newsfeed 2 for example.

When querying `post`, I can simply query it by:

```sql
select p
from post p
where p.newsFeed = :newsFeed
and p.status in (:statuses)
order by p.created desc
limit 20
```

Using the above example, if we're querying newsfeed 1, statuses would include `[VISIBLE_ADMIN, VISIBLE_ALL]` for our user, however querying newsfeed 2 with the same user would include `[VISIBLE_ALL]` only.

Let's say we have the following data in the `post` table:

| id | news_feed_id | status | title | content | created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | VISIBLE_ADMIN | Feed 1 | Admin only | 2022-01-01 19:30:00 |
| 2 | 1 | VISIBLE_ALL | Feed 1 | All can view | 2022-01-04 19:30:00 |
| 3 | 2 | VISIBLE_ADMIN | Feed 2 | Admin only | 2022-01-02 19:30:00 |
| 4 | 2 | VISIBLE_ALL | Feed 2 | All can view | 2022-01-03 19:30:00 |

The above query perfectly fine for a *single* news feed, however when trying to curate a feed from multiple feeds, I run into an issue where status can no longer be applied on a per newsfeed basis. For example, `where p.newsFeed in (:newsFeeds)` won't do.

Essentially, if we use our example where our user can view `[STATUS_ADMIN, STATUS_ALL]` on newsfeed 1 and just `[STATUS_ALL]` on newsfeed 2, the desired output would be:

| id | news_feed_id | status | title | content | created |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | VISIBLE_ALL | Feed 1 | All can view | 2022-01-04 19:30:00 |
| 4 | 2 | VISIBLE_ALL | Feed 2 | All can view | 2022-01-03 19:30:00 |
| 1 | 1 | VISIBLE_ADMIN | Feed 1 | Admin only | 2022-01-01 19:30:00 |

If I could follow the logic of something like this, it would work perfectly. (Not an actual query, just trying to illustrate what I'm going for)

```
select p
from post p
where p.newsFeed in (:newsFeeds)
(and p.status = [:newsFeed1Statuses] and p.newsFeed = 1)
(and p.status = [:newsFeed2Statuses] and p.newsFeed = 2)
...
order by p.created desc
limit 20
```

Alternatively, I could run multiple queries, one per newsfeed and collate them on the application layer, however pagination gets out of hand as I can't guarantee offsetting each query will return unique results or won't skip over any results without storing messy counters in the application.

Not sure where else to go here, and I've run out of terms to google. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "It's tricky to explain this one but I'll try my best :)" -- Then a [example] is even more required than it already is... [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables and/or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: @stickybit done :)

Comment: Where is the table that stores the relationship between users and feeds?

Comment: @stickybit Its calculated on the application layer and passed into the query as an array of statuses for that user and the newsfeed in question. Since data is sourced from multiple locations to build this array, there is no single table to use.

Comment: Is there a query to get it? Over multiple tables if necessary?

Comment: Otherwise you have to pass all that to the database and are pretty close, just some more operators: `... WHERE p.status = [:newsFeed1Statuses] AND p.newsfeed = 1 OR p.status = [:newsFeed2Statuses] AND p.newsfeed = 2 OR ...` (the `IN` isn't needed anymore, you have the news feed IDs already in there)

Comment: @stickybit Unfortunately not, as I'll be circumventing the applications permission interface (which is fairly complex in and of itself, especially as it considers inheritance on multiple objects and has a really good cache to keep performance lean)

Comment: I see. Application centric design instead of data centric design. Well, that'll likely bite, sooner or later... So, like I already wrote, if that data isn't available in the database, you need to pass it to it, one way or another. Maybe you could also pass it as derived table or CTE using `FROM`-less `SELECT`s and `UNION ALL`s and join on that. But I guess that's not that much less messier and probably a bit harder to understand than a Boolean expression.